# Projected Coordinate System issue using GDAL and qgis when defining x and y

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, pyqgis, proj

I have a `numpy.array` which I would like to save as GeoTiff using GDAL in python. The array was created using the following PCS in mind:

> +proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=48 +lat_0=48 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

where `lat_0=48` and `lon_0=0` are the standard latitude and longitude where there should be no distortion. I looked at this [guide](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-raster-from-array) but with no success. The problem is that when I define the `rasterOrigin` in degrees and define `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` in metres this does not seem to work and when I load the raster in qgis the raster is misplaced. See the example below taken from the guide I pointed out but tweaked. 
The

> outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))

does not seem to work and the image is placed at the bottom left corner taken from the lat/lon details in the PCS and not from the `SetGeoTransform` which are different.

```
import gdal, ogr, os, osr
import numpy as np


def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):

    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.SetProjCS( "myproj" )
    outRasterSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS( "WGS84")
    outRasterSRS.SetLCC(53.5,53.5,53.5,0,0,0)
    outRasterSRS.SetLinearUnits("Meter", pixelWidth)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()


def main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
    reversed_arr = array[::-1] # reverse array so the tif looks like the array
    array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,reversed_arr) # convert array to raster

if __name__ == "__main__":
rasterOrigin = (-20,40)
pixelWidth = 10
pixelHeight = 10
newRasterfn = 'test.tif'
array = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])


main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array)
```

Comment: pixel height will almost certainly be -10 (to do with image vs geographic origins)

Comment: @iant pixel height is in metres - ie 1 pixel every 10 metres

Comment: But the image origin is at the top and the geographic origin is at the bottom, thus commonly we define rasters as having negative height to make the maths easier. So you pixel height will be -10m (unless the GDAL python bindings take care of that for you)

Comment: @iant that is done by reversed_arr up in the main func but the problem I am having is to do with where the image is placed on the canvas rather that that. pixel height and width are fine.